# How to generate Assets from typescript plugins in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

### Context

Migration Angular 4 + Angular Seed to Angular 6 + Angular cli

### Problem

I'm using dynamic loading of plugins inside of one of my component using SystemJS

```
SystemJS.import("client/plugins/" + this.pluginElement.type + "/" + this.pluginElement.type + ".js")
```

If I run the application actually, I have:

```
http://localhost/client/plugins/dapChart/dapChart.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Indeed, the js file is not present as an Asset.

In the src/client/plugins folder I have a set of modules written in Typescript that I can freely used in my application.

I would like to find a way to tell to angular CLI to compile my plugins folder and consider the result as an asset and copy it like it is inside of my dist folder.

### Options

In my mind, I see 3 options (without any evidence if any of these is good):

- Check how to customize the build Angular-cli
  https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21
  But I'm completely new and will spend I think lot of time to check
- Compile manually the plugins folder and put it inside of a "pluginCompiled" folder and declare it as Assets in Angular.json with

  ```
   tsc -p src/client/plugins --outDir src/client/assets/plugins
  ```

  But it's very annoying to stop serve, compile and then launch ng serve back
- Create a sub project (workspace) in Angular.json that will compile plugins and put it inside of a "pluginCompiled"

### Question

How can I put my transpiled plugins into my build output directory with Angular 6 / Angular cli

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot how I did it myself but you can added the cli config file.

In the angular-cli you might do something like:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "client": [ "plugins": [ ] ], //something like this
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if it's still the case in Angular 6 ? with the Angular.json

Comment: Couln't find that anywhere.
But for dev and prod I use it myself, for a config file.